# How can I get git commit message when I commited?

Tags: node.js, git, npm, husky

How can I get git commit message when I commit? I use husky.

I already tried to get commit message when it's prepare-commit-msg.

pacakgejson

```
{
  ...
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  ...
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged",
      "prepare-commit-msg": "cd ../tweet-git && node index.js"
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

tweet-git/index.js

```
require('child_process').exec('git rev-list --format=%s --max-count=1 HEAD', function(err, stdout) {
    const stdoutArray = stdout.split('\n')
    let commitMessage = `【tweet-git】\nプロジェクト: 「project」にcommitしました\n`
    commitMessage += stdoutArray[1]
    console.log('commitMessage', commitMessage);
});
```

stdout will be undefined. Please help, Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track, but there are a couple things going on here that seem off.

1. Your command (`git rev-list --format=%s --max-count=1 HEAD`) would get the message from the **last** commit made, not the one currently in progress. This would be `undefined` if you are making your first commit, and is probably not what you want to be using if your eventual goal is to use the current commit message.
2. In order to read the *current* commit message, you can't use `git rev-list` or `git log`, or anything that reads back prior commits. Taking a look at Husky, it looks like it doesn't pass the message along as an argument either, and most people recommend grabbing the filepath of the stored message through Husky's set `environment variable` and then using FS to read it (links: [1](https://gitlab.giondesign.com.au/vuejs/vuetify/blob/v1.4.1/scripts/prepare-commit-message.js), [2](https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/113), [3](https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/514#issuecomment-519489016)).

Based on the above observations, here is an updated `tweet-git/index.js` that should use the current commit message:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// Tweak this to match the root of your git repo,
// below code assumes that git root is one dir above `/tweet-git`
const gitRootDir = __dirname + '/../';

const messageFile = path.normalize(gitRootDir + '/' + process.env.HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS.split(' ')[0]);
let commitMessage = `【tweet-git】\nプロジェクト: 「project」にcommitしました\n`
commitMessage += fs.readFileSync(messageFile, {encoding: 'utf-8'});
console.log('commitMessage', commitMessage);
```

> Please note the warning about needing to tweak `gitRootDir`; the path that Husky provides is relative to the root of the git initialized folder, and not absolute, so your current setup would require some tweaking. This is part of why most people put `package.json` at the project root level, and then in scripts, don't use `cd scripts && node my-git-hook.js`, they just use `node scripts/my-git-hook.js`.

Comment: It's working now. I can catch the message. Thank you for the datails.

Comment: Unfortunately process.env.HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS is no longer a thing. They say to use $1, but I'm not really sure how to reference $1 in a script like this.